# Is it possible do code coverage for manual testing on .net server which has phalanger for compiling php code?

Tags: php, .net, code-coverage, manual-testing, phalanger

Is it possible do code coverage for manual testing on a .NET server which has phalanger for compiling php code?

Answer (score 0):

Phalanger compiles code into .NET assemblies. If you specify debug option, PDB files are generated as well. That is all you need to run code coverage.

So ensure your web.config contains following

```
<phpNet><compiler><set name="Debug" value="true" />
```

Note this will produce debug build of DLL files. Currently Phalanger has no option to build in Release with PDB files.